# Python matplotlib repository ubuntu 10.10

Tags: python, svn, matplotlib, non-ascii-characters

Dear matplotlib-user and developer,
I just wanted to use the latest version from the subversion-repository which I obtained from

svn co https://matplotlib.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/matplotlib/trunk/matplotlib/lib/matplotlib/

Then I tried to load it from python and I obtained the error:

```
>>> import matplotlib
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "matplotlib/__init__.py", line 104
SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xd0' in file matplotlib/__init__.py on line 104, but no encoding declared; see http://www.python.org/peps/pep-0263.html for details
```

The reason is pretty clear since my subversion installation runs on a machine which has russian as its default language. The subversion command does the following replacement:

```
__version__  = '1.1.0svn'
__revision__ = '$Revision: 8900 $'
__date__     = '$Date: 2011-01-06 20:55:16 +0100 (Чт., 06 янв. 2011) $'
```

Does anybody know how I can configure (i)python to work out of the box?
Thank you in advance, all the best!

Answer (score 0):

matplotlib no longer uses these svn keywords (it doesn't even use svn anymore) so should no longer be an issue.